# Git bare repository doesnt reflect changes made from push

Tags: git

First of all, yes there are a lot of topic out there and it is overwhelming to the point that I get more confused rather than pin-pointing out the right stuff.

For starters, I am learning git and trying to apply it to my first project.

My set up is like this:

## Remote Repository: Linux `/opt/projectFolder`

Note that the `projectFolder` contains initial files in it.

The following command I run:

`git init --bare` <-- doesnt work, it seems I am having errors because I have a `config` folder which my project uses, so it conflicts with the git, i don't know how to fix it.

So what I did is:

```
> git init
> git add .
> git commit -m"Initial Files"
> git --bool core.bare true
```

That worked without any errors, now for

## Local Repository: Win10 C:/git/projectFolder

I run:

```
> git clone user@192.168.xx.xx:/opt/projectFolder
```

it cloned the repository successfully, now I tried to edit some text file from the initial files with it and then i run:

```
> git add .
> git commit -m"Test commit"
> git push
```

when I checked the linux remote repo the changes on the files didn't reflected BUT if I clone it on other computers the changes are reflected

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Did the answer help you? If so maybe consider accepting the answer, or if not provide more information so that we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

The *thing* you are missing is that a **bare** repository has no files for you to look at.

From the docs at [git-scm.com/docs](https://git-scm.com/docs) see [this explanation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corebare) about what the `core.bare` setting does

> **core.bare**
>
> If true this repository is assumed to be bare and has no working directory associated with it. If this is the case a number of commands that require a working directory will be disabled, such as git-add[1] or git-merge[1].
>
> This setting is automatically guessed by git-clone[1] or git-init[1] when the repository was created. By default a repository that ends in "/.git" is assumed to be not bare (bare = false), while all other repositories are assumed to be bare (bare = true).

I did not know that you can turn a repository post-initialization into a bare repository, but it seems to have worked for you.

In my opinion you should have gotten a

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
```

error, but that might depend on the `git` version.

---

The file changes you expect to see only live in the **bare** repository as commit objects in binary form (I won't go into details)

But everything is there under the `refs/` and `objects/` folders.

Hope that explains enough.

Comment: so How can I reflect those changes on the remote repository aka production ?

Comment: I would recommend you check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1434230/1988796