# Pushing to remote git server

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-remote

I setup an Ubuntu server with openssh and git, nothing else is on there. It is a VM on my LAN. I created a dir under home dir called sites, in there is my main site where I want to push to. Ran these commands:

```
mkdir -p mysite.git
cd mysite.git
git init --bare
```

Then from my workstation I ran:

```
git remote add origin steve@10.0.0.15:sites/mysite.git
git push origin master
```

It seemed to push it with no errors, however when I browse the dirs on the git server I can't locate any of the files. Am I missing something?

Comment: what happens if you `clone` the repository to some other location? are the changes there? how do you access the *bare repository on the server*? using `gitweb`, ssh/terminal/, ...?

Comment: Is your question answered? If so please accept it, if not provide more information in order to help us to help you

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the same question, but very similar answer:
[Git bare repository doesnt reflect changes made from push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46540937/git-bare-repository-doesnt-reflect-changes-made-from-push/46542876#46542876)

TLDR:
`bare` repositories have no files to browse (those repositories don't have a working copy)

Create a *normal* git repo and search for how to automatically pull after changes are pushed.

Yes, you can push to any git repository, not only bare ones.

---

**Edit:**
Maybe check this answer for inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1434230/1988796