# Git - git push origin master returns Everything up-to-date but in remote files not updated

Tags: git

I have a project in local, I ran `git init` from remote. I ran `git status` and got `nothing to commit, working directory clean` then ran `git push root@mysite.com:/home/mysite/public_html/.git master` from local. It returned `cdf0879..d49d488  master -> master` which means pushing was successful. In order to get sure that it has pushed correctly I ran it again and the returned value was `Everything up-to-date`. I updated a file named `script.js` and ran `git add .` then `git commit -m "First Edit"` then `git push root@mysite.com:/home/mysite/public_html/.git master` However when I run `git status` from remote it returns:

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#       modified:   script.js
```

How can I fix it that if I add, commit and push from local to update remote too?

Comment: Git should return an error if you attempt to push to the current branch in a remote repo. What do you mean by "I run `git status` from remote"? How are you connecting to the remote server? Are you using ssh or something simlar?

Comment: I have disabled that by `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore`. I'm using putty and connecting with ssh.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265729/what-are-the-consequences-of-using-receive-denycurrentbranch-in-git for an explanation.

Comment: Explanation of what? I just don't know why remote is not being updated. As I said at first it was bare, I had deleted all files and directories inside `.git` directory in remote and pushed fresh one from local.

Comment: See my answer below with a direct quote from one of the answers in the question that I linked.

Comment: From the path names I gather you are trying to deploy via git push to a non-bare repo. It is [probably not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433870/git-how-to-make-remote-directory-update-when-pushed-to). You should probably have a bare repo and a hook, that updates your `public_html` or whatever.

Comment: Git isn't really about *files*. Git is all about *commits*. You don't push files to another Git; you push entire commits. It's true that commits contain files—or more precisely, contain a reference to a snapshot of all of your files as of their state when you made the commit—but fetching or pushing commits from repo A to repo B just adds the commits to the receiving Git. Regular files appear in the *work-tree* in which you do work, and that does not, and should not, get updated just because someone added a new commit.

Comment: Good explanation. So how can I UPDATE the files too when I push them?

Answer (score -1):

`git push` does not do what you think it does:

> the `git push` command only updates the branch and `HEAD` references on the remote repository. What it *doesn't* do is also update the working-copy and staging-area in that non-bare remote.

If you type `git log`, you will see that all of the commits from your push exist in the repo. However, as the above states, your working tree will not be updated.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25044077/1440565)